# Does it make sense to have more mixtures than classes in a GMM

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution

If I have M classes, does it ever make sense to have a Gaussian Mixture Model with K>M components, with multiple components predicting one class?

I see this as having multiple Gaussians learning different aspects of the data in a given class, and specialising in that particular aspect, but I'm not sure if I am making poor assumptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your goal is classification, this is sensible if the shape of your classes is far from being elliptical. In such cases, fitting a single Gaussian will lead to poor classification performance because of potential outliers - the variance will be very large in order to accommodate for those, as the model is not robust. What you are effectively doing is fitting a mixture model to each class.

Comment: i did this for the MNIST dataset, I noticed that a larger number of classes performed better. How would one go about fitting a GMM to each class if the test data could be from any class? I suppose my approach would be the way to go?

Comment: Mixture models are typically estimated using a variant of the EM algorithm. You need to set up a joint likelihood where the test data has unknown class membership and the training data is used to estimate the class location scale for the normal mixture.

Comment: If you are using R for your analysis, the package **mclust** by Fraley and Raftery implements the single normal mixture. There is also work by Paul McNicholas (see his webpage), with associated packages **pgmm** and **mixture**. I dunno if they cover mixture models within each class; if not, you may need to implement bespoken code, but their papers should be a starting point on how to do so.